# django-registration: form_valid() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)

Tags: django, django-registration

I am trying to extend registration form to include additional field.
I get the following error in django-registration.

> ERROR: form_valid() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)  File
>   "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/registration/views.py", line 35, in
>   post

Using *django-registration 1.0*

Code:

```
class ExtendedRegistrationForm(RegistrationForm):
    profile_type = forms.CharField(max_length=30)

...

class ExtendedRegistrationView(RegistrationView):
    form_class = ExtendedRegistrationForm
    success_url = '/thanks/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        #do some processing
        return super(ExtendedRegistrationView, self).form_valid(form)  


url(r'^myreg/register/$', ExtendedRegistrationView.as_view(), name='registration_register'),
```

Comment: Add your findings as a response and accept it rather then update the question. This is how it's done here in SO.

Comment: For folks landing here (as I did) with a related but slightly different "register() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)" error.  django-registration-redux verson 1.2 changed the parameters for the register method.  If you are subclassing RegistrationView, you may be running into this breaking change.  https://django-registration-redux.readthedocs.org/en/latest/upgrade.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

form_valid:

```
def form_valid(self, request, form)
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Updated code:


    def form_valid(self, request, form):
        #do some processing
        return super(ExtendedRegistrationView, self).form_valid(request, form)